# Upload a huge amount of images to the viewpager from internal storage android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a huge number of files that I need to upload and place in the viewpager. It can be several thousand images. How can I correctly implement the loading of a large number of images so that the application works and does not crash ?

Comment: You do it in the same way as with a small amount of images. What is the problem? But... What is this uploading where you talk about?

Comment: @blackapps i mean loading images from internal storage

Comment: Then change title of post and text of post.